# A python script that reads files from directory path into SQLite database

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'm trying to write a python script that goes to a specific path and read all files into SQLite table(the contents within the files are irrelevant). Once the files are in SQLite database I want to be able to loop through and generate MD5 Sum, Source Directory and created Date for each file. So when I later query by created dates I'll get list of files with their MD5 and Source Directory.

I was only able to add files from the path into SQLite but wasn't able to do much. I did try using Pandas DateFrame but that wasn't much helpful.

[This what I have so far]

```
import sqlite3
import os
import pandas as pd

directory = "/unixhomes003/Desktop/"
#create connection
conn = sqlite3.connect("dbfile1.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

#Creating and inserting into table
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS filenames (filename TEXT UNIQUE)""")
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    cur.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO filenames (filename) VALUES (?)", [(filename,)for filename in      filenames if filename.endswith("")])
    conn.commit()

# Reading the table into a Pandas DataFrame
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM filenames", conn)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query, columns = ["filname"])
print(df)
```

Comment: `filename.endswith("")` is always true, since every string ends with an empty string.

Comment: "wasn't able to do much" -- what more do you want to do? How did your result differ from what you expected?

Comment: @Barmar I did this filename.endswith("") so I can read every file in the directory. And the code I shared only adds the files from the given path into sqlite tabe and doesn't do any of the fucntionalites I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why do you think you need that to read every file? Just leave out the `if` condition and it will read everything.

Answer (score 0):

you're on the right track with reading the files into an SQLite table. To generate the MD5 sum, source directory, and created date for each file, you can iterate over the files in the directory and retrieve the necessary information using Python's os module. Here's an updated version of your code that includes the additional functionality:

```
import sqlite3
import os
import hashlib
import pandas as pd

def calculate_md5(file_path):
    """Calculate the MD5 sum of a file."""
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        data = file.read()
        md5 = hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
    return md5

directory = "/unixhomes003/Desktop/"
# Create connection
conn = sqlite3.connect("dbfile1.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

# Creating and inserting into table
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS filenames (filename TEXT UNIQUE, md5 TEXT, source_directory TEXT, created_date TEXT)""")
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(""):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            md5 = calculate_md5(file_path)
            source_directory = os.path.dirname(file_path)
            created_date = os.path.getctime(file_path)
            cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO filenames (filename, md5, source_directory, created_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (filename, md5, source_directory, created_date))
    conn.commit()

# Querying the table
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM filenames", conn)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query, columns=["filename", "md5", "source_directory", "created_date"])
print(df)
```

Comment: I keep getting errors --->
sqlite3.OperationalError: table filenames has no column named md5

Comment: You have to delete the previous table you've created, then again run your code, your previous table doesn't have an md5 column
Or just simply change the table name from filenames to sth else and then run the code :)

Comment: please check as answered, if your problem is solved, thanks
@voyager1

Comment: It only printed out the filename and created date, didn't produce the MD5 hash or source directory.   This is what the output look like -->                                               
                                     filename  ...      created_date
0          ALL_CST_2307027.stil.gz  ...  1694796394.11105
1      SSN_ALL_SCAN_239012.gz  ...  1694796394.11303
2     ALL_SCAN_230427_1.stil.gz  ...  1694796394.11502
3     EDT_SSN_ALL_230427_1l.gz  ...  1694796394.11705